# The black hole paradox

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, entropy, unitarity

I recently read in the news that Stephen Hawking claims to have solved the [Black Hole Information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox). I researched a bit about the paradox and the research that Stephen Hawking did to solve it.
However, I happened to stumble across several sites that claim that the paradox hasn't been solved yet. So which is true? And what exactly is the solution proposed?

- [Stephen Hawking Hasn't Solved the Black Hole Paradox Just Yet](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/stephen-hawking-hasn-t-solved-the-black-hole-paradox-just-yet/)
- [Did Stephen Hawking just solve Black Hole's Information Paradox?](http://nerdist.com/did-stephen-hawking-just-solve-black-holes-information-paradox/)

Comment: A solution has been proposed by Gerard't Hooft and Leonard Susskind in the HOLOGRAPHIC PRINCIPLE. Check out this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle

Answer (score 2):

The paradox is not solved yet because so far Hawking has only given a 1-page proposal ([The Information Paradox for Black Holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01147) ) on how to solve the problem. The details are still missing, but they will appear in a future work with M.J. Perry and A. Strominger.

Basically the proposal is that the information is conserved, because particles that fall into the black hole cause a supertraslation (a particular symmetry of the metric linked to the gravitational memory effect) that leaves an imprint on the outgoing (evaporating) particles.